# Getting Null Pointer Exception While reading value from Config Properties File in Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, nullpointerexception, config

```
package com.HybridFramework.testbase;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class TestBase {

public WebDriver driver;

 public Properties a1;
 public File f1;
 public FileInputStream file;
public void loadPropertiesFile() throws IOException{
        Properties a1 = new Properties();
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        //f1= new File("E:\\Selenium-2017\\HybridFramework\\src\\main\\java\\com\\HybridFramework\\config\\config.properties");
    f1 = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/com/HybridFramework/config/config.properties");
    System.out.println("lola");
    file= new FileInputStream(f1);
    a1.load(file);

    f1 = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/java/com/HybridFramework/config/or.properties");
    file= new FileInputStream(f1);
    a1.load(file);

    }
    public void getPropertiesData(){

    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {
    TestBase test = new  TestBase();
    //test.getBrowser("firefox");
    System.out.println("Start");
    test.loadPropertiesFile();
System.out.println(test.a1.getProperty("Username"));
    test.a1.getProperty("testname");
}



 }
```

---

Below is my properties file which I am referencing to.

config.properties file

```
Username=Bhanu
Password=password
url=https://www.google.com
```

---

or.properties file

```
test=test1
testname=login
```

Error is Below

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.HybridFramework.testbase.TestBase.main(TestBase.java:61)

Comment: Which line is 61? Add the whole stacktrace to the question?

Comment: Getting error at line System.out.println(test.a1.getProperty("Username"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared an instance property of type `Properties` but never initialized.
Use `a1 = new Properties();` instead of `Porperties a1 = new Properties();` in your `loadPropertiesFile()` method.

Comment: It does not matter how many properties file you load into the Properties object.

Comment: @optimistic_creeper Thanks it works after using a1= new Properties();

Answer (score 0):

Use environment to get property from properties file first. 
Then you can set it to System property and afterward you can use from System.getProperty()